# Use LiveData in LifecycleObserver

Tags: android, android-activity, android-livedata

I want to use LiveData in my LifecycleObserver, but I have to pass in an Activity. How do I get this?

```
public class ChatFragmentLifecycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {


    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    void onCreate(LifecycleOwner owner) {


        ChatViewModel chatViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(*here I need the Activity*).get(ChatViewModel.class);    
}
```

Comment: Depends on if you can get a `ViewModelStore` or a `ViewModelStoreOwner` in there somehow instead

Comment: Do you know some good documentations or exampels for this?